# my JSONobject is replacing previous one

Tags: java, android

I want to have a json file like this:

```
{

"resu0":
{"item":"value"}

"resu1":
{"item":"value"}

"resu2":
{"item":"value"}

}
```

which "resu" and "0,1,2,..." are came from an intent extra.

And I'm using this code for mu purpose:

```
private void createsome(String str, int pn, String name,String value){
    try {

        JSONObject koli = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject page = new JSONObject();
        page.put(name, value);
        koli.put(str + pn, page);
        File json = new File(mypath,"myfile.json");
        FileWriter jsw = new FileWriter(json);
        jsw.write(koli.toString());
        jsw.flush();
        jsw.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Exxx", e.toString());
}
}
```

But I' getting just the last one and all new jsonobjects are replacing the previous ones instead of adding. for example if I leave the app when my intent number is "5" my whole jsonfile will be like this:

```
{
"resu5":
{"item":"value"}
}
```

I know I have a very small misplace problem but I can't find it.

Comment: are you calling this method in a loop ?

Comment: Probably you need to recover the content of the file, set it as a JSONObject, then add the new node to your JSON root node, and write the file again. If you try the blackbelt's option is posible that you build a malformed JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
FileWriter jsw = new FileWriter(json);
```

with

```
FileWriter jsw = new FileWriter(json, true);
```

this way thte `FileWriter` is opened in append mode